# react native vector icons and expo vector icons not showing up on Android device using eas build (fine on iOS and when using expo start)

Tags: android, expo, visible, invisible, react-native-vector-icons

I'm building an app using Expo and React Native, and have been trying to figure out how to get react native vector icons (or expo vector icons) to show up in the standalone version of my app on Android. They show up in the managed version (running "expo start", or "expo start --no-dev --minify" or "expo publish". But when I use "eas build" (or "expo build") and upload to Google Play, they all disappear (they show up via TestFlight on iOS devices, however). (There's nothing -- no x, no indication of anything). Since I can't edit the android/app/build.gradle (as suggested for react native vector icons), I'm not sure what to do.

I've been trying to figure out what's different in the different environments, and when I stringify parts of the icon and print it to the screen, in both the managed and standalone versions, the app has things like the name and size of the icon, but the owner disappears (I'm not sure what that is), and the type when the icon appears is function icon(), whereas when it's not visible, it's function b(). (I can include more about the two functions, if that's helpful, but I just thought I'd start with this question). I'm working in JavaScript, and so I don't know how to change the type, or what's happening to change that. I've tried so many different things (linking react native vector icons, importing the icons with/without curly braces, installing the newest version of react native vector icons, trying different things to see if I could somehow change the build.gradle file, etc). If anyone has ideas, let me know! Thanks!